# Why doesn't vim-sneak's label-mode work even after enabling it?

Tags: vimrc, plugin, movement

I wanted [lightspeed](https://github.com/ggandor/lightspeed.nvim)-like features in Vim (without having to install Neovim).

I installed [vim-sneak](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak) and followed the directions to enable "label-mode":

```
let g:sneak#label = 1
```

But when invoking sneak, labels don't show up and I still have to use `;` and `,` to move between matches.

Why isn't vim-sneak's label-mode working, even though I enabled it according to the directions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.

In the [sneak documentation](https://github.com/justinmk/vim-sneak/blob/master/doc/sneak.txt#L316-L320) it says:

```
g:sneak#label = 0

    0: Disable |sneak-label-mode|.

    1: Enable |sneak-label-mode| if the Vim |+conceal| feature is available.
```

I'm on macOS and was using Apple's default Vim version. [Apple's default Vim isn't complied with the `+conceal` feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52452738/why-is-apple-vim-compiled-without-conceal-feature). I used vim --version to confirm this.

Guided by that SO thread, I installed vim from homebrew:

```bash
brew install vim
```

[After a restart of the shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313708/apples-vim-always-used-instead-of-homebrew), `vim --version` now showed the +conceal feature.

And sneak's label-mode works!

Comment: Here's my "build it yourself" script for macs: https://github.com/benknoble/Dotfiles/blob/master/links/bin/compile-vim (needs bash with `readarray`)